# Avoiding deprecation warning when using FastUtil IntList from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, deprecation-warning, fastutil

FastUtil contains optimized collection implementations that avoid autoboxing overhead. To notify programmers of unintended autoboxing, for example when using `IntList`, they marked the `Integer get(int)` method as deprecated, suggesting to use `int getInt(int)` instead. this leads to a deprecation warning when using the array index syntax with such lists:

```
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints.IntArrayList

private fun test() {
    val list = IntArrayList(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    println(list[0]) // deprecation warning on this line
}
```

I tried redefining `get` as an operator function, but this does not seem to work because of "Extension is shadowed by a memeber".

```
operator fun IntArrayList.get(i: Int): Int {
    return this.getInt(i)
}
```

Is there any other way to use array index syntax without deprecation warning and without suppressing all other deprecations?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe there is. You could write a wrapper which would be a non-trivial amount of work.

Other primitive collection libraries don't necessarily have this problem, e.g. [Trove's `TIntList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/) can use `int get(int offset)` because it doesn't extend `List<Integer>`. Same for [HPPC](http://carrotsearch.github.io/hppc/releases/0.7.3/api/).